# How to define array like parameter in gradle project extension

Tags: plugins, gradle

I want to construct an extension in gradle plugin code to realise some config like

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo"
    }
    maven {
        url "http://maven.bbpd.io/content/groups/public"
    }
}
```

there're two maven sub elements here!
I could handle the case with one maven sub element, i could write something in plugin like
`project.extensions.create('repositories',RepositoriesExtensionClass)`
However when it comes to this case. How could I handle it.

Comment: Wouldn't this be `project.extensions.create('repositories', RepositoriesClass)` ?

Comment: yes, typo. Any idea for my question？

Comment: In your extension class, define a method `maven(Closure closure)` which does the required processing.

Comment: with one maven element I do something like project.extensions.create('repositories', RepositoriesClass), and project.repositories.extensions.create('maven', MavenClass), Could you elaborate a little bit for your solution.